# Curved end of border-bottom in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my border bottom look like this:

[image]

With one curved end.  Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The CSS I'm trying to use is `border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;`.  The code looks like this:

```
<div class="title">
    lorem ipsum
</div>

.title {
    border-bottom: 10px solid $mainRed;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

I also tried `border-radius: 10px;` which gives me the same result except both ends are curved.  Increasing this number just makes the line slope upwards.  How can I make the line look correct?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is not possible within default borders, as `border-radius` controls the radius around the element, not a single border edge.

I would recommend faking it with a pseudo-element:

```css
div {
  max-width:50vw;
  padding-bottom:25px;
  position:relative;
}
div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:red;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quippe: habes enim a rhetoribus; Quodsi ipsam honestatem undique pertectam atque absolutam. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Urgent tamen et nihil remittunt.</div>
```

Comment: I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: @Grumpy include a working example in your answer and then we'll continue the discussion.

Comment: Done. I don't see how they are different? If they are, please explain it to me, as it looks like the same effect. I love to learn, not trying to sound sarcastic.

Comment: @Grumpy the idea was to put the content **inside** the div where it belongs. You just introduced an empty element to achieve the same effect the pseudo-element from my solution was intended to provide without polluting the HTML. I would recommend reading up on [Semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) and specifically the considerations of separating content and presentation into HTML and CSS respectively. If a solution to a presentation problem exists without introducing non-semantic HTML it is always preferable.

Comment: Great idea! My designers colleagues will be pleased :D

Comment: Nice approach ! The framework I use (sapui5) seems to already make use of the ::after pseudo-class so I managed to obtain the same effect using the ::before pseudo-class. in case this helps anyone ;)

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if this is the best solution, but there it go:

```
<style>
.title .underline {
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="title">
   lorem ipsum
   <div class="underline"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -5):

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question `border-top-right-radius` controls the top right corner of the element, not the bottom border as requested.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -5):

Add this to your CSS:

```
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

underneath your other CSS. It should end up liek this:

```css
.title {
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quippe: habes enim a rhetoribus; Quodsi ipsam honestatem undique pertectam atque absolutam. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Urgent tamen et nihil remittunt.
<div class="title"></div>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question `border-top-right-radius` controls the top right corner of the element, not the bottom border as requested.